# Keycloak public key format

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

When I access the metadata of my realm of Keycloak via endpoint *https://my-keycloak-host.com/auth/realms/my-realm*, I can get the "public_key":

```
{
  "realm": "my-realm",
  "public_key": "MIIBIjANBg...",
  "token-service": "https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect",
  "account-service": "https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/my-realm/account",
  "tokens-not-before": 0
}
```

When I use that `public_key` to parse the JWT token issued by keycloak in my microservice it fails, it looks like I need to transform this public key to a format that starts with string `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and ends with `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

I wonder what is the current format of the keycloak `public_key` & How can I transform the keycloak public key to the that format with "BEGIN" and "END" strings?

Answer (score 5):

That API's public_key is single long string.
You just to break multiple lines by 64 size

then add **-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----**

result of API call string , to break every 64 bytes with new lines.

and add **-----END PUBLIC KEY-----**

It will convert into [PEM(Privacy-Enhanced Mail)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) format

I made a simple python program.

You needs to change the URL

```
import requests
import json

def convert_public_key(text):
    line_length = 64
    lines = []
    for i in range(0, len(text), line_length):
        lines.append(text[i:i+line_length] + '\n')
    return  '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' + \
            ''.join(lines) + \
            '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n'

REALM_URL='http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test'
response = requests.get(REALM_URL)
data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(convert_public_key(data['public_key']))
```

This is terminal output

```
$ python get-public.py
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgeVGoYuRpoVttadu+ecg
mpzXiHsEF/9JbLZnxBIiBkdZAUICMbCp2EV+Q+R1HUcjaUs5ZNKVLqbINa0kMRaZ
B9/B8DidkPgMQx4iFg2inwKV8ZdAkbAuXltmfla1CwwoZlT+x/YTM7f5XoJlGkNU
XRF908ubFMlR8jTnw6w220nlduzAsz5Da1b4wyhmWXgCokGbSta7HXJD9O3z8Hf7
MfhLwLA9KTscCGLpoZSh94APX9Agr/8GE14GbpdRDTrhi2oBmdi/9hnSbXUms4ew
bxQGvuo0JDznLTCGeYempqSSE9vg5OrGPWxTT6cOs60C/KdmxqW8aVBYJOe7a2Os
uwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

It is as same as Keycloak UI.

[image]

You can find this location.
{your-realm}/Realms Setting/Keys/RS256 RSA Public Key button

[image]

You can verity public key is correct from this web site.

```
https://russelldavies.github.io/jwk-creator/
```

[image]

This is setting steps

1. public Key Use: **Signing**
2. Algorithm : **RS256**
3. Key ID:  copy from UI  **kid** value
   [image]
4. Use the public key by python program (upper text)
5. Click this button
6. Get JWK - it should be matched Keycloak Certificate API - attached end of image
   API response JSON should be match JWT (red circle number 6) content.

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

[image]

[image]

"n" is **[public key modules](https://medium.com/@bn121rajesh/understanding-rsa-public-key-70d900b1033c)**

"e" is **public key exponent**

This public key can verify JWT

Comment: This answer is worth it's content in gold!

Comment: Hey Meezaan, Thank you very much. It give me a courage.